# Mapping not working for specific Controller

Tags: spring-boot, url

I am a rokie with Spring Boot.
Now I am having e problem with a GetMapping path that it is not recongized by the application.

This is the controller:

```
package com.pablop.survey.web.app.controllers;

import java.util.List;

//import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; import org.springframework.ui.Model; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping; import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

//import com.pablop.survey.web.app.models.entity.Question; //import com.pablop.survey.web.app.services.IQuestionService;

@Controller 
@RequestMapping ("app/survey/question") 
public class QuestionController {

//  @Autowired //   private IQuestionService iQuestionService;

@GetMapping("/questionlist")

public String questionlist(Model model) {

//      List<Question> questionList= iQuestionService.questionList();
return "questionlist";
}

}
```

This is my HTML that redirect to my controller

```
<tbody class="card-body">

                            <tr th:each="survey: ${surveyList}">
                                <td class="h5">

                                        <h4 th:text="${survey.surveyName}"></h4>
                                    <div>
                                        <a th:href="@{'/app/survey/question/questionlist'}"
                                            th:text="${'List of questions'}" class="text-primary"></a>
                                    </div>

                                </td>

                                <td><a th:href="@{'/app/survey/edit/'+ ${survey.id}}" th:text="${edit}"
                                    class="btn btn-warning"></a></td>

                                <td><a th:href="@{'/app/survey/delete/'+ ${survey.id}}"
                                    th:text="${delete}" class="btn btn-danger"
                                    onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure to delete this item?')"></a></td>

                                <td><a th:href="@{''}" th:text="${startTest}"
                                    class="btn btn-success"
                                    onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure to delete this item?')">
                                </a></td>


                            </tr>
```

When I search in the browser the following url http://localhost:8080/app/survey/question/questionlist

a 404 error appears.

questionlist.html is located inside templates folder like other html files that are working.
Beside I do not why there is a red diamond over that file in the explorer.

If somebody can explain me what I am doing wrong I will appreciate it

Comment: Do other Controller method calls return a non-404 response?

Comment: Hi John
Thank you for your interest helping me!. I found the problem, was related with the pom file. After I close the project and open again all the URL were working. 
Thanks again.
Best regards
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Hello I once faced a similar problem was solved by changing @Controller to RestController, also the URL in RequestMappings try to start them with "/". Hope this helps